# CQS pattern with Spring / Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, command-query-separation

I'm developing a `Java`/`Spring`/`Hibernate` application that adheres to the `CQS` (`Query Command Separation`) pattern.

Put simply:

- our `domain model` is only used by `Commands` which describe some operation that needs to be done on the domain model;
- all read operations are done by a `QueryService` that bypasses the `domain model` so it can optimise (using `projection`) each query on a use case basis.

The domain model maps to `MySQL` database by using `Hibernate`.

*I know there's a longrunning debate about separation between domain and persistence model. However, I'm convinced that nowadays Hibernate has become so flexible that you don't have to make hard sacrificies on the domain model. This way, you don't get a one-to-one mapping between domain and persistence model.
Additionally, all DB-related stuff can be abstracted away by using Layer Supertypes.*

My questions:

1. If I use `Hibernate` `Query` (or `Criteria`) using projection in my `QueryService`, I'm in fact using my domain model instead of plain SQL. **Isn't this a breach against the `CQS` pattern...?**
2. I could opt for using plain SQL in my `QueryService`. Is there any good SQL framework out there that gives me the possibility to **build Queries without using domain model AND easily binding results into JavaBeans**? The results are typically graphs, so it would be nice to easily bind these to some nested JavaBean structure.

Comment: The framework is called hibernate... Also do you see in CQS any mention you MUST use SQL...

Comment: I didn't say it must be SQL. I'm just saying that I'm using SQL. What CQS doesn't mention is using the domain model for query operations. And my question is that when I'm using Hibernate HQL or Criteria, my queries will be based on the domain model that Hibernate uses in the background for all metadata.

Comment: 'The framework is called Hibernate...' -> Did I mention something else....

Comment: You want to map sql to objects, that is exactly what hibernate is for. I suggest a read of the documentation especially about results mapping and custom object (all that is explained in the reference guide).

Comment: I'm aware of that. What I'm wondering about is the following: If I map sql to objects with Hibernate it's done by the Metamodel that Hibernate manages. This metamodel is based on my domain model (which contains all meta-annotations). So isn't this a breach against CQS as I'm in fact (implicitly) using my domain model for query operations. I've seen it this way in many projects, however I've a feeling this isn't 100% OK....

Comment: And I'm going again to tell you go read the reference guide, especially about results mapping. You are asking question and making statements on incomplete knowledge, extend your knowledge.

Comment: Weird... I've more than 10 years of experience in Hibernate including mapping sql to (custom) objects. I'm just asking a theoretical question. By the way, who are you to judge on my knowledge???

Comment: The fact that you ask the question leads me to believe that you haven't read [this section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-scalar-named-queries) of the reference guide. You can perfectly well execute plain sql with hibernate for which you don't need your domain model, you could even create "entities" which represent your read-only model (did that on quite some occasions, which works pretty well).

Comment: I'm aware of that section, I've used it several times and it indeed works pretty fine. In fact that section is exactly my point. Because you have to define those annotations on the @Entity classes which make part of my domain model. It feels weird to define such annotations for query purposes on my domain model which in fact doesn't have anything to do with view related operations. Or am I just too theoretical on this one?

Comment: The named queries can also be placed in xml the `orm.xml` or on the `package-info.java` instead of the entities. If you use spring you could even externalize the `orm.xml`. Also creating a read-only model next to the full domain model is a very workable approach (used in on several occasion). Using views to model that (instead of custom queries) and marking in read-only (adding the `@Immutable` annotation).

Comment: @user2054927, isn't CQS only about separating the command and query _operations_, so it shouldn't matter what kinds of models you're using for queries? In any case, I'd recommend you have a look at QueryDSL if you haven't already. It makes writing queries against Hibernate entities much more fluent compared to the Criteria API.